# UIScrollView only scroll with at least 1 object inserted from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, iboutlet

I have a weird behaviour here : my `UIScrollView` only want to work when I had at least 1 object from Interface Builder.

Because I also **add some subviews dynamically** like :

```
[scrollView addSubview:player.view];
```

But it doesn't want to work **except** if I drop at least 1 item **from IB** into `scrollView`.

Note that to declare my scrollView in my header file I drag and dropped using IB and i created an `IBOutlet` :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Then I synthesize it.

Anyone experienced the same issue ?

Thanks for help and ideas.

Comment: did u try this 

[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(800, 1000)];

Comment: Well it works but I don't know why... I should not have to do this because it works with dropped items from IB.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you need to write at least a little code for the `UIScrollView` to work, at least contentSize must be set.

Add another IBOutlet for your content (eg. scrollContent) in the scrollview and set the scrollview contentsize to the bounds of the scrollContent in `viewDidAppear`

Try debugging your code. Probably your contentSize is zero in `viewDidLoad`. Thats normal, the size of the view is only know at `viewDidAppear`.

For sample code, see http://bitbucket.org/robvanderveer/scrollviewdemo.

Comment: Yes but as I previously said, why should I set the contentSize of the scrollView when it works just by adding an object from IB by drag-and-drop ?

Comment: I'm not sure,but i guess that when the nib or storyboard is loaded, it does some magic with setting the properties for you. Myself, i'm starting to work a little more in code to make sure it's done the way i like.